# Laravel 5.2 Error while simply trying to display a view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I created a view which allows the user to create a theme/post. The link to that view is in my navbar. But the problem is When I try to click the link (display the view) I get redirected to the home page without any errors whatsoever.

In the link of the navbar, i put `<li><a href="{{ route('createtheme') }}">` which simply activates the route with the name "createtheme". This route is as followed: 
`Route::get('/theme/create', 'ThemesController@create')->name('createtheme');`.
So this activated the create method in the ThemesController.php. Which is:

```
public function create()
{
    return view('themes.create');
}
```

So if I read this correctly, This is supposed to give me the right view, right? And it doesn't give me any errors so I don't know where to look.

This is the view I'm trying to display:

```
@extends('layouts.default')

@section('content')
<div class="container main-content">
    <div class="row first-row">
        <div class="col s12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-content clearfix">
                    <span class="card-title">New theme</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-content">
                    <form method="POST" action="">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="input-field col s6 has-error form-group">
                                <input id="title" class="form-control" type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title of topic">
                                <label for="title" class="active">Title of theme</label><span>Titel is mandatory!</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="file-field input-field col s6 form-group">
                                <div class="btn cyan darken-1 disabled"><span>Attachment</span>
                                    <input id="attachement" type="file" name="attachment" class="disabled">
                                </div>
                                <div class="file-path-wrapper form-group">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="geen" class="file-path validate form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col s12 form-group">
                                <textarea id="message-body" class="form-control" name="body"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col s6">
                                Hier komen opties om het onderwerp te sluiten of
                                aan te geven dat het opgelost is, alleen bij bewerken
                            </div>
                            <div class="col s6">
                                <a href="" class="btn right cyan darken-1" type="submit">Save</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection

@section('scripts')
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/ckeditor/ckeditor.js') }}">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/editor.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/blog.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/materialize.js') }}">
</script>
@endsection
```

And here are the routes that are related to this problem.

```
Route::get('/theme/create', 'ThemesController@create')->name('createtheme');
Route::post('/theme/create', 'ThemesController@store');
```

And of course the Store method:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    Theme::create($request->input()); //Dit doet hetzelfde als bovenstaande

    return redirect('/');
}
```

The middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    if ($request->user()->role_id != 2 || 3)
    {
        return redirect('/');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: I would replace the `return view('themes.create');` in the controller with a `dd('got here')` to make sure that it's actually making it to the controller method and the problem isn't in your Middleware or view.

Comment: I replaced it @DavidAllen But it still does the same thing, It just brings me back to the home page

Comment: What are you getting? A white page?

Comment: No just a refresh. Reminder that the route is inside a Middleware in web.php. Maybe that affects it?
UPDATE I  added the middleware to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem at that point:

```
  if ($request->user()->role_id != 2 || 3)
```

And more specifically in comprasion:

```
 (Integer value) != 2 || 3
```

All ingeteger values will return `true`, even `0`. E.g.:

```
 if (0 != 2 || 3) -> TRUE
 if (2 != 2 || 3) -> TRUE
 if (3 != 2 || 3) -> TRUE
```

and you get redirect. Change you code at that point for right comprasion ( you use operators not properly). 
The simplest way:

```
 $allowed_role_ids = [2,3]; // array(2,3);
 if (!in_array($request->user()->role_id,$allowed_role_ids)){
    // redirect
 }
```

Comment: I see what the problem is. If i put the routes out of the Admin Middleware it just works fine. But if i put them inside of the middleware i doesn't work? How do i fix this? @voodoo417

Comment: So my adminmiddleware needs to look something like `if ($request->user()->role_id == 2 || 3)` The admin middleware needs to see if the person that is logged in has role ID 2 OR 3. if that's the case Then everything inside of the middleware is accessible for that user.

Comment: @Feudelcosine148  ok, I have updated answer.Redirect all roles except ids equal `[2,3]`

Comment: Interesting .. I never seen such a syntax `x != y || z` already.

Comment: @Shafizadeh Me too ^)

Comment: `:-)` ..! Are you sure? Since you're the author `;-)`. Upvote anyway.

Comment: @Shafizadeh ahahah++)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this code in you controller?

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

If so, and you are not logged in. You will be redircted to the homepage.

Try

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth')->except(['store', 'create']);
}
```